# How to disable warnings in SBT console

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm new to SBT, and I like debugging scala source code in SBT console. But the console always repeats warnings like `<console>:65: warning: Unused import` for each command line. Really annoying.

How can I disable this useless warnings in SBT console while keep this check in sbt compile?
I think I should add in `build.sbt` something like `scalacOptions in console := ???`, but not sure what it should be exactly.

[Update]
I haven't went thru the tutorial about sbt, so I copied `build.sbt` from some sample project. I added `scalacOptions in (Compile, console) ...`, but it still doesn't work.

```scala
    scalacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-feature", "-unchecked", "-Xlog-reflective-calls", "-Xlint"),
    scalacOptions in (Compile, console) ~= { _.filterNot(Set("-Ywarn-unused-import", "-Ywarn-unused:imports")) },
    javacOptions in Compile ++= Seq("-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"),
    javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-Xms256m", "-Xmx2048m", "-Djava.library.path=./target/native"),
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
```

Comment: Consider using [the **sbt-tpolecat** plugin](https://github.com/DavidGregory084/sbt-tpolecat/issues) which provides a good set of flags to ensure best practices and already handle this kind of problems, like disabling some flags on the console task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a common problems like this one, you can try checking out `build.sbt` files from open source projects and see how they deal with that.

```scala
scalacOptions in (Compile, console) ~= { _.filterNot(Set("-Ywarn-unused-import", "-Ywarn-unused:imports")) }
```

This is an excerpt from `cats`. [link](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/v2.1.0-RC2/build.sbt#L855-L859)

Update:

The code I pasted above was about filtering out specific scalac flags in your code under `src/main` (`Compile`) when running the `console` command (`console`).

There are a few options that generate unused import warnings from scalac. The `cats` library was using options specific to unused import warnings (`-Ywarn-unused-import`, `-Ywarn-unused:imports`), and as such, it was only filtering out those.

In your case, the flag that is generating the warning is `-Xlint`, which also generates many other kinds of warnings too. You can remove the flags in the `Set` and add `-Xlint`, and it will stop generating unused imports warnings. However, it will also stop generating other warnings too. (It shouldn't be too big of a deal though, since it's just repl. )

Comment: Yes, I started my `build.sbt` from some example project. I tried as you suggested but still got no luck. Maybe I messed up my sbt file?

Answer (score 2):

To remove the unused import warning from newer versions of sbt add this line to `build.sbt`:

```
Compile / console / scalacOptions -= "-Wunused:imports"
```

To play around with scalac options interactively you can use the following commands in an sbt shell that you start by running `sbt` in a terminal:

Print the current scalac options used for the console/scala REPL:

```scala
show console/scalacOptions
```

Add or remove single options:

```scala
set Compile/console/scalacOptions += "-XmadeUpOption"
set Compile/console/scalacOptions -= "-Wunused:imports"
```

Add or remove several options at once:

```scala
set Compile/console/scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xopt1", "-Xopt1")
set Compile/console/scalacOptions --= Seq("-Wunused:imports", "-Wunused:params")
```

Print the options again to verify that they have taken effect:

```scala
show console/scalacOptions
```

Note that the option set from the sbt shell are not persisted, they are only used for the remainder of the shell session.